# Snapshot for certain index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch. I'm trying to create a snapshot for backup in elasticsearch, but I don't want to snapshot the whole cluster. I'm still getting used to the terms here so I might have addressed something wrong, but the idea is basically:

```
localhost:9200
|
|--index_1
      |
      |---type 1
             |---log_1
             |---log_2
      |---type 2
|--index_2
      |
      |---type 1
      |---type 2
```

Currently,

- I can successfully create snapshot for `index_1` and `index_2`,
- so `localhost:9200/_snapshot/index_1` shows the setting,
  `type 1`.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: what is index_1.1. Is that a `type` inside `index_1`

Comment: yes, sorry for bad naming. I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description above 1.1 isn't an index, its a document type inside an index.

The index is index_1. Inside it there are documents of 2 different types, which can be queried separately.

I don't believe you can dump a document type from inside an index without some custom scripting.

If you decide to build a script you might want to look at  https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump. It might be easy to modify for your needs.

Not only can you select particular indexes for backup, but it can dump it in json format so it can be imported to other versions of ElasticSearch, provided the mappings are still valid in the new version.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was still getting used to all the terms for ES. Yes, I was indeed talking about backup-ing a type in an index. I might just back up an index in this case. Spending time on writing a new script is not desired for my case right now. Thanks though

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. You do not need to take snapshot of whole cluster. For taking snapshot of individual index you can follow below code:

```
       PUT /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1
             {
         "indices": "index_1",
         "ignore_unavailable": "true",
         "include_global_state": false
              }
```

Comment: Is it applicable for ELK stack version 6.8 ?

Comment: Here's the documentation of the endpoint for all versions: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/create-snapshot-api.html